# GIT source control in CCNET built all project when trigger happend

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I have install CCNET on windows 7Ent to make autobuild source from a GIT(Ubuntu) Server.
Evething is ok but i have a big problem :

My repo structure :

```
enter code here
  REPO1
        --module 1
        --module 2
        --module 3
        --module 4
```

When CCNET detect a trigger it will build from the 1st module to last module.
I dont wanto to do this way.Just build which module has been modified.
Could you please tell me how to do this ?

My ccnet CONFIG:

```
<project name="DA 5.0" queue="01" queuePriority="01" category="01">
<artifactDirectory>&pathToArtifactsDirectory;Dashboard 5.0\</artifactDirectory>
&workingDirectory;
<webURL>http://&buildServerAddress;/ccnet/server/&buildServerName;/project/Da /ViewLatestBuildReport.aspx</webURL>
&modificationDelaySeconds;
<triggers>
  <intervalTrigger seconds='30' buildCondition='IfModificationExists'/>
  <scheduleTrigger time='03:00' buildCondition='ForceBuild' name='Scheduled'/>
  <scheduleTrigger time='11:00' buildCondition='ForceBuild' name='Scheduled'/>
</triggers>
<state type="state" directory="&pathToStatesDirectory;Dashboard 5.0\" />

    <sourcecontrol type="git">
      <repository>&gitAddress;</repository>
      <branch>master</branch>
      <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
      <fetchSubmodules>true</fetchSubmodules>
      <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe</executable>
      <tagOnSuccess>false</tagOnSuccess>
      <commitBuildModifications>false</commitBuildModifications>
      <commitUntrackedFiles>false</commitUntrackedFiles>
       <workingDirectory>&pathDB5MainCheckoutDirectory;framework</workingDirectory>
      <timeout>3000000</timeout>
    </sourcecontrol>


<tasks>
  <nant>
    <executable>&pathToNantFile;</executable>
    <baseDirectory>&pathToBuildScriptsDirectory;Da\</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs>-D:projects_to_build=framework</buildArgs>
    <buildFile>cruise.build</buildFile>
    <targetList>
      <target>automate</target>
    </targetList>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>3000</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  </nant>

</tasks>
<publishers>
  <merge>
    <files>
      <file>&pathDB5MainCheckoutDirectory;framework\build\test-reports\*Test.dll-results.xml</file>
      <file>&pathDB5MainCheckoutDirectory;framework\build\test-reports\Test*.dll-results.xml</file>
      <file>&pathDB5MainCheckoutDirectory;framework\build\test-reports\simian.xml</file>
    </files>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger />
</publishers>
```